When does a template parameter of incomplete type become complete?
By the time that the constraints of a<b>'s default constructor
are being checked, shouldn't type d—and thereby also type b—
be considered complete? GCC accepts the construction of an object
of type b, but both Clang and MSVC reject it.
And, it's not just the construction of a b object that leads to
this result. Even just aliasing nested type b::d (i.e. using w = b::d;)
will run into the same discrepancy.
Oddly, this difference in compiler behavior only seems to occur
when user-providing the default constructor of type a
while constraining it with c<d>. What is the expected outcome
of this program?
template<typename T>
concept c = requires { sizeof(T); };

template<typename B>
struct a {
    struct d : B {};
    a() requires c<d> = default;
};
struct b : a<b> {};
auto v = b{}; // clang nope, gcc ok, msvc nope

Demo

Clang's error message:
<source>:6:16: error: base class has incomplete type
    6 |     struct d : B {};
      |                ^
<source>:2:24: note: in instantiation of member class 'a<b>::d' requested here
    2 | concept c = requires { sizeof(T); };
      |                        ^
<source>:2:24: note: in instantiation of requirement here
    2 | concept c = requires { sizeof(T); };
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~
<source>:2:13: note: while substituting template arguments into constraint
expression here
    2 | concept c = requires { sizeof(T); };
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:7:18: note: while checking the satisfaction of concept 'c<a<b>::d>'
requested here
    7 |     a() requires c<d> = default;
      |                  ^~~~
<source>:7:18: note: while substituting template arguments into constraint
expression here
    7 |     a() requires c<d> = default;
      |                  ^~~~
<source>:7:5: note: while checking constraint satisfaction for function 'a'
required here
    7 |     a() requires c<d> = default;
      |     ^
<source>:9:12: note: in instantiation of template class 'a<b>' requested here
    9 | struct b : a<b> {};
      |            ^
<source>:9:8: note: definition of 'b' is not complete until the closing '}'
    9 | struct b : a<b> {};
      |        ^
<source>:10:12: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'a<b>'
   10 | auto v = b{};
      |            ^
<source>:7:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: constraints not satisfied
    7 |     a() requires c<d> = default;
      |     ^
<source>:7:18: note: because 'd' does not satisfy 'c'
    7 |     a() requires c<d> = default;
      |                  ^
<source>:2:24: note: because 'sizeof(T)' would be invalid
    2 | concept c = requires { sizeof(T); };
      |                        ^
<source>:5:8: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor)
not viable: requires 1 argument, but 0 were provided
    5 | struct a {
      |        ^
<source>:5:8: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor)
not viable: requires 1 argument, but 0 were provided
    5 | struct a {
      |        ^

MSVC's error message:
<source>(6): error C2504: 'b': base class undefined
<source>(6): note: the template instantiation context (the oldest one first) is
<source>(7): note: while evaluating concept 'c<a<b>::d>'
<source>(6): note: while compiling class 'a<b>::d'

